# how to draw axes passing through the origin in a 3D plot using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a 3d plot like the following, such that axes pass through the origin with ticks on them.

[image]

PS: I could do that for 2D plots using matplotlib (the following figure). I searched a lot to do the same for 3D plots but I did not find any info.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict yourself to just `matplotlib` then we can use `quiver3d` plot as shown below. But the results may not be very visually appealing. You can see [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html) how to add 3D text annotations.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(0,2)
ax.set_ylim(0,2)
ax.set_zlim(0,2)
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=32)

# Make a 3D quiver plot
x, y, z = np.zeros((3,3))
u, v, w = np.array([[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,1]])

ax.quiver(x,y,z,u,v,w,arrow_length_ratio=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d quiver plot]

Comment: Thanks Amit. But the problem is here the x, y, z axes do not pass through the origin unless the lower limits of axes (xlim, ylim, zlim) are zero.

Comment: And if I draw the axes as arrows (using quiver), how can I put the ticks on them?

Comment: There would be no automatic way to do that. I guess you will have to add the ticks and labels as text annotation in a loop. But it will not be the simplest solution.

Comment: Another idea would be to draw using 2d plot commands but such that the figure "appears" 3d. But again this is not an automatic solution. We will have to calculate angles and lengths.